# Отправить данные сервера клиенту

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер

У меня есть клиент и сервер. Клиент отправляет массив и номер индекса с помощью которого хочет получить число из массива. Сервер находит это число в массиве и выводит его.

Сервер:

```
#include <yvals.h>
#include <ymath.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
 
int main()
{
    WSAData v_2_0;
    int WSAStartup_ = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &v_2_0); 
 
    if (WSAStartup_ != 0) 
    {
        cout << "Initialization error" << endl;
 
    }
 
    SOCKET ServerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if (ServerSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket not created" << endl;
 
    }
    sockaddr_in getting = {};
    getting.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    getting.sin_port = htons(4567); 
    getting.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    int bind_ = bind(ServerSock, (sockaddr*)&getting, sizeof(getting));
    if (bind_ == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
 
    listen(ServerSock, SOMAXCONN);
    if (listen(ServerSock, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        cout << "Network port not found" << endl;
    }
    
    sockaddr_in clientAddr = {};
    int nAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    SOCKET accept_ = accept(ServerSock, (sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &nAddrLen);
    if (accept_ == INVALID_SOCKET) 
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }
    char buff[255] = {};
    char mess[255] = {};
    string word;
    int n, res;
    int sum = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int len = recv(accept_, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        if (len <= 0)
        {
            cout << "The client broke the connection" << endl;
            break;
        }
        word = (string)buff;
        n = stof(word.substr(0, word.find_first_of(' ')));
        string word_ = word.substr(word.find_first_of(' '), word.find_last_of(' '));
        sum = stof(word.substr(word.find_last_of(' ') + 1, word.size()));
        cout << "The sum of numbers =" << sum << endl;
        cout << "The arithmetic mean :" << sum/n << endl;
        res=sum / n;
    }
    int sock2;
    char buf2[255];
    itoa(res, buf2, 10);
    SOCKADDR_IN InetAddr;
    sock2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    InetAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    InetAddr.sin_port = htons(5151);
    connect(sock2, (struct sockaddr*)&InetAddr, sizeof(InetAddr));
    send(sock2, buf2, sizeof(buf2), 0);
    closesocket(ServerSock);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause>>void");
}
```

Клиент:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    WSAData v_2_0;
    WORD make = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int WSAStartup_ = WSAStartup(make, &v_2_0);
    if (WSAStartup_ != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error starting WinSock" << WSAStartup_ << endl;
 
    }
 
    SOCKET ClientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (ClientSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket not created" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
 
 
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connection to server successful" << endl;
    }
 
    sockaddr_in getting = {};
    getting.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    getting.sin_port = htons(4567); 
    getting.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
 
    int connResult = connect(ClientSock, (sockaddr*)&getting, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error! " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
 
    }
    else cout << "Connection established" << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        char buff[255] = {};
        char mess[255] = {};
        int n, num, s;
        int sum = 0;
        int option;
        string word = "";
        string fin = "";
        cout << "Enter a sequence of numbers (Enter 1)" << endl;
        cout << "Exit (Enter 2)" << endl;
        cout << "Your number:";
        cin >> option;
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "input n: ";
            cin >> n;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << i + 1 << " / " << n << " : ";
                cin >> num;
                sum += num;
            }
            word = to_string(n)+' '+to_string(sum);
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            cout << "exit ? ";
            cin >> word;
            break;
        }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
        {
            buff[i] = word[i];
        }
        if (strcmp(buff, "exit") == 0) 
        {
            cout << "The connection to the server has been dropped" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            int send_ = send(ClientSock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0); 
            if (send_ == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
            }
        }
    
         
    }
    int listener;
        int sock2;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char buf2[255];
    int bytes_read;
    listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5151);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    listen(listener, 2);
    sock2 = accept(listener, (sockaddr*)&addr, 0);
        cout <<"Result: "<< buf2 << endl;
    if (closesocket(ClientSock) == SOCKET_ERROR) { cout << "Error closesocket" << endl; }
    WSACleanup();
    cout << "Press any key to continue" << endl;
    closesocket(ClientSock);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause>>void");
}
```

Проблема в том, что сервер не отправляет результат клиенту. Я пробовал с помощью создание новых сокетов так и с использованием предыдущих.

Comment: У Вас в коде сервера (в том, что можно назвать циклом обработки сообщений) есть код для чтения, но нет кода для отправки ответа. Да, там ниже есть какой то код для записи, но в какой то другой сокет, о котором клиент не в курсе. А телепанию в винсок ещё не подвезли

Comment: @KoVadim у меня был вариант использовать в сервере команду send сокет который принимал информацию(accept_) от клиента и засунуть, как вы сказали, в цикл обработки сообщений, но пока не понял почему клиент его не получает если использовал в accept сокет который отправляет данные серверу

Comment: есть случающий сокет (ServerSock) - он участвует в bind, listen и accept, когда клиент удачно подключается, то accept возвращает другой сокет (accept_) с которым уже можно работать на чтение-запись, обмениваться данными с клиентом. А ServerSock опять готов к тому, что бы принимать (accept) новых клиентов. Писать-читать в ServerSock  не нужно.

Comment: @KoVadim Тогда в клиенте какой надо сокет использовать для recv? Я все еще не понял

Comment: а в клиенте нужен всего один сокет. Им подключаетесь, им читаете-пишете.

Comment: @KoVadim ага...значит в данном случае для сервера и клиента, чтоб отправить данные сервера к клиенту надо использовать сокеты которые подключаются, читают и пишут как у меня ServerSock и ClientSock

Comment: не совсем. Читайте внимательно о ServerSock, Внимательно-внимательно